# Amazon Pay - Simultaneous one-time and recurring purchases

Tags: payment-gateway, amazon-pay

We are planning to integrate Amazon Pay to our website that offers subscription & a one-off charge upon signup.

According to Amazon Pay [docs](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/eu/amazon-pay-automatic/enable-advanced-scenarios.html#simultaneous-one-time-and-recurring-purchases), it is possible with extra stuffs must be implemented.

Our problem is we have trouble finding a concrete example combining recurring & one-off charge in the single workflow. We use PHP.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a [code sample](https://amzn.github.io/amazon-pay-sdk-samples/recurring.html) on the developer documentation for recurring payments, that you can adapt for the additional one-off charge.

Essentially, what you do is: if the buyer wants to buy a subscription along with an one-off item, you create a Billing Agreement like described in the code sample linked above. After it has been created (using the [ConfirmBillingAgreement](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/eu/amazon-pay-api/confirmbillingagreement.html) API call), you can [authorize](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/eu/amazon-pay-api/authorizeonbillingagreement.html) and [capture](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/eu/amazon-pay-api/capture.html) the desired amount (e.g. the amount for the first month of the subscription + the price of the one-off item).

If the buyer decides during the checkout to drop the subscription, use the [CreateOrderReferenceForId](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/eu/amazon-pay-api/createorderreferenceforid.html) API call to create an Order Reference Object out of the Billing Agreement. From here on, it's essentially a regular one-time payment scenario, so you can follow the remaining integration steps described [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/eu/amazon-pay-onetime/request-an-authorization.html).